# Problems making a connection using method

Tags: php

I have been unsuccessful trying to make a connection using a method in my code. Previously I used the $con variable as per my code. This made the connection and all seemed to be OK. P.S all my paths are correct.

```
 <?php

$con = new dbmember();
$con->openDB();

//
// this WORKS but I want to use my function to do this for me instead
//$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","password","db_name");
//  
$user=$_POST['user']; 
$password=$_POST['password'];

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){


//To ensure that none of the fields are blank when submitting the form if
if(isset($_POST['user']) && isset($_POST['password'])) 
    {    

        $user = stripslashes($user);
        $password = stripslashes($password);
        $user = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $user);
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $password);

        //SQL Injection Ahoy! I know...but future versions aim to be robust!

$sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='users' and password='password'";
$result=mysqli_query($con, $sql);

$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);

if($row[0]==1)
{
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
    $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = "true";
    header("location:index.php");
}
        else
        {
            print ('<div id="error">Acess denied, wrong username or password?</div>');
        }
        }
        else
            {
            print ('<div id="error">Enter something!</div>');
        }

}

    ?>
```

This is my method

```
<?php

require("assets/configs/db_config.php");

class dbmember {
    /* DB connection handle */

    var $conn;


  function openDB() {


// 1. Create a database connection
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost" , "username", "password","db_name");
if (!$conn)
{
    $this->error_msg = "connection error could not connect to the database:! ";  
    return false;
```

Error given :

```
Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, object given in C:\xampp\htdocs\c\login.php on line 98

Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, object given in C:\xampp\htdocs\c\login.php on line 99

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, object given in C:\xampp\htdocs\c\login.php on line 104

Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\c\login.php on line 106
```

I can only assume $con must not be passing correctly. Can you offer a solution?

Comment: And yes the function file as been called, forgot to add.

Comment: This calls for basic debugging. http://php.net/mysqli_error

Comment: the clue is in the error message - you can't pass your object to mysqli functions and expect them to know what it is. You must pass the connection resource returned by mysqli_connect.

You could store that in your class and make it available, or provide some wrapper functions in your class which do it for you.

Comment: Yes, you assume correct. `$con` is an object. And your mysqli handle resides in `$con->conn`. (If it gets assigned at all).

Comment: **Listen to @PaulDixon and @Mario!** They speak the truth... and you're doing it wrong.

Comment: you realy should use a hash-function (e.g. MD5) for the password. saving them plaintext is not a good idea! this can be done easy with `$password = md5($password);`

Comment: @Alex *Please* don't recommend MD5. (Sure, plaintext is **worse**, but MD5 is only the slightest of improvements.)

Comment: @Alex True what Michael says. The latest fad is the [crypt()^](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) function with a *'strong strength'* ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of

```
$result=mysqli_query($con, $sql);
```

try

```
$result=mysqli_query($con->conn, $sql);
```

and change

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost" , "username", "password","db_name");
if (!$conn)
{
```

to

```
$this->conn = mysqli_connect("localhost" , "username", "password","db_name");
if (!$this->conn)
{
....
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What should I be returning. Just true, or something like ` $this->conn = $conn;
return true;
}`  OR `return $this` ?

Comment: your `$con` is an object of type `dbmember()` . I just used the `var $conn` in your object to store the connection details and use it for subsequent queries.